# Sense Hat rainbow tests forever; unable to access Pi

Tags: pi-3, vnc, sense-hat

Disclaimer: I'm *incredibly* new to coding (I first looked at a command line nine weeks ago for a class and the class has taught me nothing thus far). Explain as you would to an illiterate ten-year-old.

I have an RPi3B with a Sense Hat connected. I'm using VNC Viewer on a Mac with an ethernet cord to access the Pi, and I have no other way of getting to it, as the monitor I used to originally connect is no longer available to me (unless someone can tell me how?). My Pi was working perfectly earlier today, until I accidentally clicked reboot instead of shut down. I waited for VNC Viewer to reconnect, which it didn't, and then I unplugged my Pi.

Now it will not boot. The red PWR light stays on consistently, the green LED flickers intermittently, but I cannot connect to it via VNC Viewer ("no such host is found") and the Sense Hat is permanently stuck on the rainbow test display.

Is there any way I can fix it on my own? Or do I need a different computer/monitor/something to access the Pi?

Comment: check if the LEDs are flashing an error code .... google `RPi error codes`

Comment: Don't know if a Mac has this normal usb connector but for an emergency connection to a text console on the raspi you can use a `TTL to serial adapter` which does not cost more than 10 EUR. With this you can connect to the three GPIO pins from the serial interface on the raspi. You will also see the boot up messages.